# How to wrap text in table cell at hyphen?

Tags: css, line-breaks, css-tables, word-wrap

I found the text-wrap and overflow-wrap CSS 3 properties, but they don't seem to do anything.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

How to wrap text at hyphens within a table cell? Testing on Chrome 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `table-layout:fixed`. Tested in Chrome 15 and IE7.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>htqdrs-sdfwwwf-dfaaa-com-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff-kljdfgg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {    
    table-layout:fixed;
    width : 50px;
    border : 1px solid #000;    
    word-wrap : break-word;
}
td {
    width : 50px;
}
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ZjCy/1/

Answer (score 1):

You want the proposed (non-standard) CSS 3 Text [`hyphens`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#hyphenation) property:

```css
td { hyphens: manual }
```

Note that this is only [supported in FF, Chrome, and Safari; it is unsupported in IE or Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/hyphens).

Comment: Not working for me on Chrome 14. In the Inspect Element info, hyphens is crossed out. Also, in live example from the link you provided, it is crossed out for p element.